# Apollo Server's passed in dataStore is not visible to class

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

There is the following extension of `DataSource` class:

```
class UserAPI extends DataSource {
  constructor({ store }) {
    super()
    this.store = store
  }
  initialize({ context }) {
    this.context = context
  }

  async findOrCreateUser({ email: emailArg}){

    console.log(emailArg)
    const email=
    this.context && this.context.user?
    this.context.user.email
    :emailArg
    console.log(this.store)
    if (!email || !isEmail.validate(email)) return null;

    const users=await this.store.user.findOrCreate({ where: { email } });

    return users && users[0] ? users[0]:null
  }

  .....
}
```

Which is passed into the ApolloServer constructor like this:

```
dataSources:()=>({
        LaunchAPI: new LaunchAPI(),
        UserAPI:new UserAPI({models})
    })
```

And accessed within the resolvers like this:

```
login: async (parent, { email }, { dataSources }) => {
    
        const user = await dataSources.UserAPI.findOrCreateUser({ email });
        ...
```

The problem that I always encounter when trying to execute the mutation is that `this.store` within the `UserAPI` class is `undefined`. In case you are wondering, this is the models I am passing (and I am awaiting them to sync in the server initialization):

```
const sequelize=new Sequelize(
  "postgres",
  "postgres",
  "password",
  {
    dialect:'postgres'
  }
)


const UserFactory=(sequelize,DataTypes)=> {
  const user=sequelize.define('user', {
  createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  email: DataTypes.STRING,
  profileImage: DataTypes.STRING,
  token: DataTypes.STRING,
})    
  return user
}

const TripsFactory=(sequelize,DataTypes)=>{
  const trips=sequelize.define('trip', {
  createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
  updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
  launchId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  userId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
})
  return trips
}


const models={
  User:UserFactory(sequelize,Sequelize.DataTypes),
  Trips:TripsFactory(sequelize,Sequelize.DataTypes)
}

module.exports=models
module.exports=sequelize
```

I have tried multiple solutions but nothing seems to work. When I am logging the passed `models` to the class it logs the database just fine... Could You please help me to understand my mistake? Thank you very much!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.models.User.findOrCreate()`?

Comment: @slideshowp2 Thanks for your answer! I have tried that ,yet it was not the root of the problem !